# G-WAN - How to return Status Code: 200 OK if request URL = 541+ characters?

Tags: httprequest, g-wan, server-configuration

I'm using G-WAN Web App. Server v7.12.6.

How to return valid Status Code: 200 OK if request URL has a total of 541+ characters including the 25 parameters?

ajaxGet(URL, method) where method is GET or PUT (same result)

Request URL:

```
http://myWebsite.ca:xx/?createCompany.c&legalname=mycomp&dba=mycomp%20dba&www=www.myWebsite...
```

createCompany.c

```
#pragma link "pq"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h"
#include "gwan.h"
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  u64 start = getus();
  PGconn *conn;
  PGresult *res;
  char DBrequestString [1000] = "";

  char *legal_name = 0, *dba = 0, *www = 0; //...+ 22 more

  xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);

  get_arg("legalname=", &legal_name, argc, argv);
  get_arg("dba=", &dba, argc, argv);
  get_arg("www=", &www, argc, argv);
  //...+ 22 more

  char requestString[1000] = "SELECT create_company('%s','%s','%s', ... + 22 more);";
  sprintf(DBrequestString, requestString,legal_name, dba, www, ... + 22 more);

  conn = PQconnectdb("host=x port=x dbname=x user=x password=x");

  if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK){
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQfinish(conn);
    xbuf_cat(reply, "{\"message\":\"Connection to database failed !\"}");//message Json format
    return 200;
  }
  res = PQexec(conn, DBrequestString);

  printf(" --> %s\n",PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0));
  xbuf_cat(reply, PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0));//return one line Json format

  PQclear(res);
  PQfinish(conn);
  printf("TEMPS D'EXECUTION: %.2Fms\n\n",(getus() - start)/1000.0);
  return 200; //return OK
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question - I don't have access to the source code righ tnow but looking at the [G-WAN API](http://gwan.ch/api) on the website made me think that either `READ_XBUF` or `MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` might help.

Typically, `READ_XBUF` would be used in a `G-WAN HANDLER` to augment (if needed) the connection buffer while `MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` is a one-time setting that can be changed at any time (and even before the server starts, thanks to the `init.c` script).

I think that just enlarging the `MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` value (which purpose is to prevent lage-entity DoS attacks) would do the job because it is most likely that G-WAN automatically enlarges the `READ_XBUF` on a per request basis when reading from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response.

I updated the script createCompany.c to raise the limit (as per your example):

```
u32 *old_entity_size = (u32*)get_env(argv, MAX_ENTITY_SIZE);
u32  new_entity_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MiB    
*old_entity_size = new_entity_size; // raise the limit to 2 MiB
```

It's that possible the MAX_ENTITY_SIZE it's exclusively for POST request?

Raising the MAX_ENTITY_SIZE limit will work for GET/PUT requests also?

Actualy, I would like the limit to remain as initialy setup by default by G-WAN, useful for the other .c scripts,
but to raise the limit for GET/PUT requests only for this particular script createCompany.c

Any script.c example how to raise the limit for READ_XBUF?

Comment: *handlers/main_rewrite.c* shows how to act before G-WAN in increasing *READ_XBUF*. I will have to check the source code to tell about *MAX_ENTITY_SIZE*.

Comment: Gill, thanks for giving us the opportunity to use G-WAN for free.
It’s a great web server. Great for use with C.
Using G-WAN from 2012, will never change for another web server.